# How to access Android data from Fragment in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning Android programing, and I can not figure it out how to share data between Fragment and ViewModel.

I am making application, that will have fields **IP Adress** and **IP Port** in settings.

In start page fragment I have created function `fillServerData()` which will load data from settings into **serverViewModel** object.

I have created ViewModel object in Fragment, and it works as it should be. I can initiate it in any fragment with:

```
serverViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ServerObservableData::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

And access every field with `serverViewModel.ipAddress.value.toString()`.

I have a problem with accesing data in ViemModel.kt, there I can not use

```
activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ServerObservableData::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

My question is - How I can access `serverViewModel` data outside fragment? Is there any way that I can create object in ViewModel that will read data? Can I use use data binding?

EDIT:

I want my application to connect to server so that it can retrieve data.

I have created settings fragment, where will user fill server, port, username and password data.

I have created class: `ServerObservableData : ViewModel()`, and on my start page fragment there is function `fillServerData()`, which will use `SharedPreferences` to collect values, and pass them to `serverViewModel` object. And this works great. I can get data from `serverViewModel` in any fragment. I just need to initialize it using:

```
serverViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ServerObservableData::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

My problem is that data from `serverViewModel` object, which are stored in `SharedPreferences`, I need to use in ViewModel, not the Fragment. How can I pass them from Fragment to ViewModel?

Sugestion from Kamal Nayan is ok to me, but for some reason program crashes and message is:

> UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property serverViewModel has not been initialized

But when I put `Log.i()` function so that I can track what is happening, onCreate() is called, and initialization for `serverViewModel` object is in that function. So program should not crash, because `onCreate()` has been called before `get()`.

EDIT no.2:

This is code in DocumentsFragment.kt:

```kotlin
class DocumentsFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var serverViewModel: ServerObservableData
    private val viewModel: DocumentsViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(DocumentsViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        serverViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ServerObservableData::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

        Log.i("DocumentsFragment", "onCreate")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding: FragmentDocumentsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_documents,
            container,
            false
        )

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.documentViewModel = viewModel

        return binding.root
    }

    fun getHttp(): String {
        Log.i("getHTTP", "RETURN")
        // THIS IS WHERE PROGRAM CRASHES, WHEN RETURN IS CALLED
        // ...serverViewModel has not been initialized
        return serverViewModel.ipAddress.value.toString()
    }

    fun getIP(): String {
        return serverViewModel.ipPort.value.toString()
    }
}
```

Code in DocumentsViewModel.kt

```kotlin
class DocumentsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _response = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val response: LiveData<String>
        get() = _response

    init {
        Log.i("ViewModel", "ViewModel INIT")
        testConnection()
    }

    private fun testConnection() {
        var baseUrl = "http://${DocumentsFragment().getHttp()}:${DocumentsFragment().getIP()}/rest/out"

        val orgInfo = RequestBody(
            user = "test",
            request = "x",
            signature = "x",
            requestJson = "x"
        )

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val listResult =
                    ElementApi.retrofitService.sendRequest(baseUrl, orgInfo)
                _response.value = "Success."
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _response.value = "Failure: ${e.message.toString()}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to have your data in another fragment, you have 2 solutions, first: pass the data to the new fragment, or second, create a `serverViewModel` in that other fragment that will fetch data

Comment: It is not data between fragments. It is data between fragment and viewmodel. Data in FragmentX.KT to be accessible in ViewModleX.kt. Thank you for answer.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your issue, your question is "how to access your viewmodel data outside of fragment?" what do you want to do ? and what do you mean by outside of fragment ?

Comment: I have edited post for detailed problem explanation.

Comment: You need to post more code that provide context. Your short snippets do not tell anyone _where_ you're making those calls which would lead to your issues.

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: where `getHttp` is called ?

Comment: It is called in DocumentsViewModel.kt, function `testConnection()`, in variable `baseUrl`.

Comment: You simply can't have reference of your fragment in your ViewModel, you need to move things around, your ViewModel must not know anything about Fragment

Answer (score 0):

** I'm not a Kotlin guy.**
But I use setters and getters in java like create a variable in viewModel and make its getters and setters.
And use getter to access that variable data from outside ViewModel (for example in fragment)
and setter to set the values in a variable inside viewModel from outside the viewModel.

Comment: This does not help me, since data flow is fragment -> viewmodel. I get error that **kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property serverViewModel has not been initialized**. Thank you for answer.

Comment: It means that you are using ViewModel without initializing it.

Comment: I know, since ViewModel is first created and then Fragment. If I add initialization to get method it throws **Invalid Activity**, as it should.

Comment: I tested with `Log.i()`, and Fragment is first called, then ViewModel. So why is not initialized? Since initialization is in `onCreate()`...